# I tried to make a simple fun system with increasing and decreasing numbers with input, but it doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I tried the script and its working well for the first 2 functions, but then when I added the third one, the entire page just doesn't work. Can I know why and how to fix?

I am a beginner Javascripter and I still need practices so can you guys explain someway suitable for my level?

```js
let a = 0,
  b = 1

function inc() {
  a += b
  document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = "x" + " " + "=" + " " + a;
};

function dec() {
  a -= b
  document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = "x" + " " + "=" + " " + a;
};

function input() {
  if (document.getElementById("input").innerHTML == null) {

  } else {
    b = Number(document.getElementById("input").innerHTML);
  };
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Online simple Javascript project!</h1>
<p id="x">x = 0</p><!-- Result -->
<p><br><br>Change the power here!</p><!-- // Description -->
<input id="input"><button type="button" onclick="input()">Apply</button><!-- // Button that save your power -->
<h2>Click the button to increase x</h2><!-- // Description -->
<button type="button" onclick="inc()">Increase</button><!-- // Increase -->
<h2>Click the button to decrease x</h2><!-- // Description -->
<button type="button" onclick="dec()">Decrease</button><!-- // Decrease -->
```

Comment: Note: HTML comments are in the form of `<!-- comment -->`, not `//` (that's for JS)

Comment: Probably a good idea to favor `===` (instead of `==`) and `!==` (instead of `!=`) as a beginner. `===` is strict and `==` is abstract. Abstract has more scenarios where the result isn't very intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) instead of `innerHTML` for `input`

```
function input() {
  if (document.getElementById("input").value != null){
    b = Number(document.getElementById("input").value);
  };
};
```

Comment: You don't need the `!=` since the `if` statement is truthy, as long as there is a value, it will pass. The only issue (and I know this is beyond the scope of this question), anything other than a number will throw an NaN error.